# Random out of memory exception with ConcurrentDictionary GetOrAdd

Tags: c#, multithreading

Sometimes my code gives me "Out of memory exception", it's raise randomly after 5 or 10 minutes of executing my parallel loop. The exception is throw at *File.ReadAllLines(line)* When I disable cache Timer everything works fine. I have 2 files 190MB which I read for every 5 seconds. Code part form my application:

```
class MC {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string[]>> _files = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<string[]>>();
        private readonly Timer _cache =  new Timer();

        private MC ()
            {
                _cache.Enabled = true;
                _cache.Interval = (int) Settings.Default.fileCache*1000; //seconds
                _cache.Elapsed += (sender, args) => _files.Clear();
                _cache.Start();

                Parallel.ForEach(lines, options, (line, loopState, idx) =>
                                                    {
                                                    //code
                     string[] resultStrings = {};
                     var fileKey = GetMD5Hash(line); 
                     resultStrings = _files.GetOrAdd(fileKey, new Lazy<string[]>(() => File.ReadAllLines(line),
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)).Value;
                     Fun(string.Join("", resultStrings.OrderBy(x => GetThreadRandom().Next()).Take(10)));                                           //code
                                                    }

            }

    }
```

*lines* from parallel lopp looks like (it has 100 000 000 records):

```
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
c:\a.txt
c:\b.txt
```

Comment: you should try Using StreamReader .. its a little bit more reliable imo

Comment: The `Lazy<>` doesn't look like it has any use and where/how are resultStrings , fileKey, fileName etc declared? In this snippet they don't look very thread-safe.

Comment: { } do not match up.  Format

Comment: What is this code meant to accomplish? If you clear the cache every 5 seconds, you're allocating ~380 MB to re-read the files every 5 seconds, **on top of** repeatedly randomising the order of all 190 MB worth of lines - only to throw away all but the first 10 - as fast as your loop can go.

Comment: @shambulator - I did take it to be test code, to reproduce a problem. And it seems to do that.

Comment: The content of the txt files are changed from another process so I need read them every few seconds. I need N random lines for every Fun invoke. So is there any better solution for doing that?